# How to Implement Master Detail in Ionic Framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to use Ionic Framework to build a simple Master Detail List application. I can capture the tap event on the list item but how can I load the details view after that.

```
.controller('TasksController',function($scope){

      $scope.tasks = [
          { title : "Collect Coins" },
          { title : "Eat Mushroom" },
          { title : "Find the princess" }
      ];

      $scope.showTaskDetails = function() {
          alert('show Task details');
      }

});
```

In the showTaskDetails event. How can I load a different view like Details.html?

Answer (score 2):

The Master Detail pattern is a very easy pattern to implement in Ionic, but you're going about it wrong. You want to set up the details as a separate view and route in your application.

I suggest reading my article on the topic.

http://mcgivery.com/ionic-master-detail-pattern/

Comment: In your article you are calling the details view same as Master List. Is this a typo mistake??

Comment: Which part are you referring to?